# Android seekbar change text + format editText

Tags: android

When the seekbar change i want to update the editText with the progress changed(This was successfully achieved). Now how can i format the editText value in $currency format e.g.$200,000. The seekbar is similar to this.

```
    SeekBar sk=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    final EditText tv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

    sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 }

                 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 }

                 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       tv.setText("Seek bar value is"+ arg1);


                 }
          });
```

I just want a tips in where to format the editText to display days as $200,000.. when seekbar change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$###,###");

    String value = df.format(arg1);

    System.out.println(value);
    // will output "$200,000"  if arg1 = 200000    

    tv.setText("Seek bar value is "+ value);
}
```